# How can I generate a secret key with validity period?

Tags: java, hash, cryptography, secret-key

I'm working on securing vehicle to vehicle communication.
My scenario is as follows:
vehicles generate secret keys using hash chain
uses the keys to authenticate the messages
Each message is sign with a new key, and send the message with the key
So, I'm looking for a way to assign a lifetime to each key.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

A hash function certifies that certain information has not been modified (it does not matter whether the information is encrypted or not):

```
hash = hash_function( DATA )
```

Anyone who knows the information (`DATA`) can generate the hash, so a secret key is added:

```
hash_sign = hash_function( DATA + secret_key )
```

To set an expiration value, we can add any information (the creation or expiration date depending on who controls the setting of when it expires):

```
hash_key = hash_function ( DATA + timestamp + secret_key )
```

To sign a certain message (`DATA`) with expiration (`timestamp`) you must deliver three values:

```
{
    data: "DATA",
    timestamp: "2022-02-06T18:18:02.456Z",
    hash: "base64hashkey"
}
```

To validate the message, you only need to know the secret key and calculate the hash, if someone tries to modify the `timestamp` field then the hash will not match.

This is basically what JWT does (see [RFC 7519](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#page-9))

Comment: First, the hash needs adjectives like a cryptographically secure hash. Second, The secret_key size must be mentioned since a short key can be easily searched. At least 128-bit is required. However, in the OP's scenario, one can reduce the secret size to 80 since the attack time is limited. Third, one should mention the possible hash function in Java.